# do TCP warning means packet ignored,"Wireshark (Warning/Malformed):Short segment.Segment/fragment does not contain a full TCP header (might be NMAP )"

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

I am simulating TCP for example any received tcp packet so there should be a response, And for that I have coded my server program in C and created TUN interface so clients packet read my code, The problem with my code is simply that I am getting `SYN` packets, And I am responding to it with `SYN + ACK` packet. sequence numebers and ports are correct. in wire shark I am see my SYN + ACK reponses but my client keep sending SYN packets and in middle router solicitation messages, In wire shark its says

```
Expert Info (Warning/Malformed): Short segment. Segment/fragment does not contain a full TCP header (might be NMAP or someone else deliberately sending unusual packets)
```

What this mean, I am kind of sure I am including all the valid fields as values but why am I keep getting this warning and my client is seems like ignoring my SYN +ACK packet. can anyone please take a look at this code

This  is my main function

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char *tun_ip = NULL;    /*virtual*/
    const char *remote_ip = NULL; /*physical*/
    ip4_addr_t local_ip4 = 0L;
    pthread_t tid_recv;//, tid_trans;
        void *thread_ret = NULL;
        

    _progname = argv[0];
    if (argc != 3) 
    {
        usage();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    tun_ip = argv[1];
    remote_ip = argv[2];
       if (0 >= inet_pton(AF_INET, tun_ip, &local_ip4)) 
       {
        debug("%s: invalid IP address %s\n", _progname, tun_ip);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    
    set_signal(SIGINT,  sigexit);
    set_signal(SIGQUIT, sigexit);

    
    _tun_fd = open_tun_iface(local_ip4);
    if (_tun_fd < 0 ) 
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
     


    _udp_fd = open_udp_socket();
    if (_udp_fd < 0 ) 
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    
    if (0 >= inet_pton(AF_INET, remote_ip, &_remote_ip)) 
    {
        debug("%s: invalid IP address %s\n", _progname, remote_ip);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    pthread_create(&tid_recv,  NULL, receiver,    NULL);
    
     while (!_do_exit)
        sleep(1);

    debug("** Shutting down...\n");
    close_tun_iface();
    shutdown(_udp_fd, 2); _udp_fd = -1;
    pthread_join(tid_recv,  &thread_ret);

    return 0;
}
```

This is my receiver and responder TCP thread

```
void * receiver(void *data)
{

    //struct sockaddr_in cliaddr = {0};
    int recvlen = -1;
    int writelen = -1;
    //socklen_t clilen = sizeof(cliaddr);

    while (!_do_exit)
    {
        //recvlen = rrecvfrom(_udp_fd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&cliaddr, &clilen);
        char buf[VPN_MAX_MTU] = {0};
        char buf_1[VPN_MAX_MTU] = {0};
        memset(buf,0,VPN_MAX_MTU);
        memset(buf_1,0,VPN_MAX_MTU);
        memset(buf,0,VPN_MAX_MTU);
        memset(buf_1,0,VPN_MAX_MTU);
        

        char *str_source=malloc(18);
        char *str_dest=malloc(18);
        memset(str_source,0,18);
        memset(str_dest,0,18);
        recvlen=read(_tun_fd,buf,VPN_MAX_MTU);
        if(recvlen>0)
        {

    //BUFFER received here        
        struct iphdr *iph=(struct iphdr *)buf;  
        struct iphdr *ip=(struct iphdr *)buf_1;
        int y=0;
        for(int b=0;b<(sizeof(struct iphdr)+sizeof(struct tcphdr));b++)
        {
            if(y==20)
            {
                y=0;
                //printf("\n");
            }
            
            //printf("%x ",buf[b]<<24);
            
            
            y++;
        
        }
    //      tcph->check=(tcp_chksum(iph,tcph));
        //iph->check = csum(iph, sizeof(*iph));
        char str_src[18]={0};
        char str_dest_t[18]={0};
           
           
        //printf("IN %s %s\n",get_ip_str_1(iph->saddr,str_src),get_ip_str_1(iph->daddr,str_dest_t));
        memcpy(&ip->daddr,&iph->saddr,sizeof(uint32_t));
        memcpy(&ip->saddr,&iph->daddr,sizeof(uint32_t));
        //printf("OUT %s %s\n",get_ip_str_1(ip->saddr,str_src),get_ip_str_1(ip->daddr,str_dest_t));
        //Create ip
        
        //DOUBLE CHECK FOR BYTE ORDER
        
        //ip->tot_len=iph->tot_len;
        populate_ip_some(iph,ip);
        ip->tos=0;
        ip->tos=iph->tos;
        ip->ihl         = 5;
        ip->version     = 4;
        ip->tot_len     = sizeof(struct iphdr) + sizeof(struct tcphdr);
        ip->protocol    = 6;
        ip->check=0; 
        //DOUBLE CHECK FOR BYTE ORDER
            ip->check = csum(ip, sizeof(*ip));
        ip->id=htons(100);

        //printf("before %d \n",htons(iph->check));
        iph->check=0; 
        //printf("middle %d\n",iph->check);
        //DOUBLE CHECK FOR BYTE ORDER
            iph->check = csum(iph, sizeof(*iph));

        int i=iph->ihl*4;
        struct tcphdr *tcph=(struct tcphdr *)(buf+i);
        //printf("tcp before %x\n",htons(tcph->check));
        tcph->check=0;
        printf("TCP START\n");
        tcph->check=(tcp_chksum(iph,tcph));
            printf("TCP END\n");
        //printf("tcp after %d\n",(tcph->check));
        //printf("i == %d\n",i);
        //POSSIBLY PRINT IPH for fun
        //for(int a=0;a<recvlen;a++)
            //printf("%x\n",buf[a]);
        //GET ihl SEND --  tcp
        int j=(ip->ihl*4);
        //printf("j == %d\n",j);
        int x=0;
        
        //SEEK filling
        struct tcphdr *tcp=(struct tcphdr *)(buf_1+20);
        populate_tcp_some(tcph,tcp);//Do LOOK AT THIS FUNCTION TO [SEE/CORRECT IT] >:)
        if(tcph->syn==1)
        {
               printf("syn\n");
               populate_tcp_some(tcph,tcp);
               tcp->seq=htons(1);
               tcp->ack_seq=1;
               tcp->syn=1;
               tcp->ack=1;

               tcp->source=htons(80);
    //         printf("received tcp syn = %d\n",tcph->syn);
        }
        else
        {
               populate_tcp_some(tcph,tcp);
               tcp->syn=0;
               tcp->ack=1;
    //         printf("sending tcp syn = %d ack = %d\n",tcp->syn,tcp->ack);
           
        }
        populate_tcp_some(tcph,tcp);
        tcp->dest=tcph->source;
        //printf("%d %d SOURCE PORT \n",ntohs(tcph->source),ntohs(tcp->dest));
        
        tcp->source=htons(80);
        printf("%d %d PORTS \n",ntohs(tcp->source),ntohs(tcp->dest));
        tcp->check=0;
        //TCP CHECKSUM ABOUT TRIPPLE WOW
        tcp->check=tcp_chksum(ip,tcp);
        
        //printf("tcpH = %d |  tcp = %d\n",tcph->check,htons(tcp->check));
        //IF needed make payload data
        //WRITE
        if (recvlen > 0) 
        {
            writelen = write(_tun_fd, buf_1, sizeof(struct iphdr)+sizeof(struct tcphdr));
            //debug("SR:%04d\n", recvlen);
            //debug("TW:%04d\n", writelen);
            
            if (writelen < 0) 
            {
            //debug("%s: rwrite() %s [%d]\n", _progname, strerror(errno), errno);
               //break;//NO NEED
            }
        }
        else if (recvlen < 0) 
        {
            //debug("%s: rrecvfrom() %s\n", _progname, strerror(errno));
               //break;//NO NEED
        }
        else if (recvlen == 0) 
        {
            //why
        }
    //FINALLY THEN SEND || DO WIRE SHARK 
        }
        
        // ...:)__ :) __:) ___:)___ (: __(:__ (;...  

    }

    debug("** Receiver ending.\n");
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

and this is my how I set up tun interface

```
int open_tun_iface(ip4_addr_t local_ip4)
{
    struct ifreq ifr_tun;
    int fd = -1;
    sock = -1;
  //  int mtu = VPN_PATH_MTU;

    if ((fd = open("/dev/net/tun", O_RDWR)) < 0) {
        debug("%s: Cannot open /dev/net/tun: %s. Do modprobe tun; lsmod\n", _progname, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    memset( &ifr_tun, 0, sizeof(ifr_tun) );
    ifr_tun.ifr_flags = IFF_TUN | IFF_NO_PI;// | IFF_NO_PI;
    if ((ioctl(fd, TUNSETIFF, (void *)&ifr_tun)) < 0) {
        debug("%s: TUNSETIFF error: %s\n", _progname, strerror(errno));
        close(fd);
        return -1;
    }

#if 0
    if (ioctl(fd, TUNSETPERSIST, 1) < 0) {
        debug("%s: TUNSETPERSIST error: %s\n", _progname, strerror(errno));
        close(fd);
        return -1;
    }
#endif

 sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sock < 0) {
            printf("interface socket error\n");
        debug("%s: Cannot open udp socket: %s\n", _progname, strerror(errno) );
        close(fd);
        return -1;
    }

    if (set_ip(&ifr_tun, sock, local_ip4) < 0) {
        close(fd);
        close(sock);
        return -1;
    }


    if (ioctl(sock, SIOCGIFFLAGS, &ifr_tun) < 0) {
        debug("%s: SIOCGIFFLAGS: %s\n", _progname, strerror(errno));
        printf("SIOCSIFFLAGS\n");
        close(fd);
        close(sock);
        
        return -1;
    }

    ifr_tun.ifr_flags |= IFF_UP;
    ifr_tun.ifr_flags |= IFF_RUNNING;

    if (ioctl(sock, SIOCSIFFLAGS, &ifr_tun) < 0)  {
        debug("%s: SIOCSIFFLAGS: %s\n", _progname, strerror(errno));
        printf("SIOCSIFFLAGS\n");
        exit(0);    
        close(fd);
        close(sock);
        return -1;
    }


    /*mtu = get_if_mtu("eth0", sock);*/
  /*  mtu = path_mtu_to_ip(_remote_ip, 32);
    if (mtu <= 0) {
        mtu = INTERNET_MTU;
    }

    if (mtu + VPN_OVERHEAD > VPN_MIN_MTU)
        mtu -= VPN_OVERHEAD;

    if (0 != set_mtu(&ifr_tun, sock, mtu)) {
        close(fd);
        close(sock);
        return -1;
    }
*/
    debug("** TUN opened: %s\n", ifr_tun.ifr_name);
    //close(sock);
    
    return fd;
}
```

and this is my checksum calculations

generic csum function

```
uint16_t csum(const void *data, const int length)
{
    uint16_t *accumalator = (uint16_t *)data;
    uint64_t sum = 0;

    /* Take care of the first 16-bit even blocks */
    for (int i = 0; i < length/2; ++i) {
        sum += *(accumalator+i);

        if (sum >= 0x10000) {
            sum -= 0xffff;
        }
    }

    /* Handle the ending partial block */
    if (length % 2 != 0) {
        accumalator = accumalator+ length/2; /* Point accumalator to the end block */
        uint16_t end_block = 0;
        memcpy(&end_block, accumalator, sizeof(length));
        sum += ntohs(end_block);
        if (sum >= 0x10000) {
            sum -= 0xffff;
        }
    }
  
    return htons(~sum);
}
```

and this is I calculate and handle TCP checksum calculation

```
uint16_t tcp_chksum(struct iphdr *snd_iph, struct tcphdr *snd_tcph)
{
    struct psuedo_header psh;

    psh.src_addr = snd_iph->saddr;
    psh.dst_addr = snd_iph->daddr;
    psh.rsvd = 0;
    psh.proto = IPPROTO_TCP;
    psh.len_tcp = htons(sizeof(struct tcphdr)); /* No options, and no data */

    int pseudogram_size = sizeof(struct tcphdr) + sizeof(struct psuedo_header);
    //int pseudogram_size = sizeof(*snd_tcph) + sizeof(psh);
    char *pseudogram = malloc(pseudogram_size);

    memcpy(pseudogram, (char *)&psh, sizeof(struct psuedo_header));
    memcpy(pseudogram + sizeof(struct psuedo_header), snd_tcph, sizeof(struct tcphdr));

    return((csum1(pseudogram, pseudogram_size)));
    //return (htons(csum(snd_tcph, sizeof(struct my_tcph)) + csum(&psh, sizeof(struct psuedo_header))));
}
```

int populate_ip_some(struct iphdr *o1,struct iphdr *o2)
{
o2->ihl=o1->ihl;
//o2->version=o1->version;
o2->id=htons(ntohs(o1->id)+1);
o2->frag_off=o1->frag_off;
o2->ttl=o1->ttl;
o2->tos=0;
//o2->protocol=o1->protocol;
//o2->check=0;
return 1;

}

int populate_tcp_flags(struct tcphdr *o1,struct tcphdr *o2)
{

```
if(o1->syn==1 && o1->ack==0)
{

    printf("syn received\n\n");
    o2->syn=1;
    o2->ack=1;
    o2->rst=0;
    o2->fin=0;
    return 1;
}
if(o1->syn ==0 && o1->ack==1)
{
    printf("ack received\n\n");
    o2->syn=0;
    o2->ack=0;
    o2->rst=0;
    o2->fin=0;
    return 1;
}
if(o1->syn==0 && o1->fin==1)
{
    printf("fin received\n\n");
    o2->syn=0;
    o2->ack=1;
    o2->fin=0;
    o2->rst=0;
    return 1;
}

return 1;
```

}

```
uint32_t *ik;
int x=0;
int populate_tcp_some(struct tcphdr *o1,struct tcphdr *o2)
{
    if(x==0)
    {
        ik=malloc(sizeof(int)*100);
        if(ik==NULL)
        {printf("heap\n");exit(0);}
    }
    *(ik+x)=x;
    o2->seq=htons(*(ik+x));
    uint32_t host=ntohs(o1->seq);
    if(o1->syn==1)
    o2->ack_seq=1;
    else
    {
        //DOUBLE CHECK FOR TCP. ACK_SEQ SHOULD HAVE BEEN sizeof(OF TOTAL PACKET) + 1
        //DOUBLE CHECK MAY NEED TO PASS IPHDR ipH   
        o2->ack_seq=(htons(host+1));
    }   
    o2->doff=o1->doff;
    o2->res1=o1->res1;
    o2->window=o1->window;
    o2->check=0;
    o2->urg_ptr=o1->urg_ptr;
    x++;
    return 1;
}
```

this is my netinet/ip.h which has iphdr defination

```
struct iphdr
  {
#if __BYTE_ORDER == __LITTLE_ENDIAN
    unsigned int ihl:4;
    unsigned int version:4;
#elif __BYTE_ORDER == __BIG_ENDIAN
    unsigned int version:4;
    unsigned int ihl:4;
#else
# error "Please fix <bits/endian.h>"
#endif
    uint8_t tos;
    uint16_t tot_len;
    uint16_t id;
    uint16_t frag_off;
    uint8_t ttl;
    uint8_t protocol;
    uint16_t check;
    uint32_t saddr;
    uint32_t daddr;
    /*The options start here. */
  };
```

and this is netinet/tcp.h where my tcphdr struct can be found

```
struct tcphdr
  {
    __extension__ union
    {
      struct
      {
    uint16_t th_sport;  /* source port */
    uint16_t th_dport;  /* destination port */
    tcp_seq th_seq;     /* sequence number */
    tcp_seq th_ack;     /* acknowledgement number */
# if __BYTE_ORDER == __LITTLE_ENDIAN
    uint8_t th_x2:4;    /* (unused) */
    uint8_t th_off:4;   /* data offset */
# endif
# if __BYTE_ORDER == __BIG_ENDIAN
    uint8_t th_off:4;   /* data offset */
    uint8_t th_x2:4;    /* (unused) */
# endif
    uint8_t th_flags;
# define TH_FIN 0x01
# define TH_SYN 0x02
# define TH_RST 0x04
# define TH_PUSH    0x08
# define TH_ACK 0x10
# define TH_URG 0x20
    uint16_t th_win;    /* window */
    uint16_t th_sum;    /* checksum */
    uint16_t th_urp;    /* urgent pointer */
      };
      struct
      {
    uint16_t source;
    uint16_t dest;
    uint32_t seq;
    uint32_t ack_seq;
# if __BYTE_ORDER == __LITTLE_ENDIAN
    uint16_t res1:4;
    uint16_t doff:4;
    uint16_t fin:1;
    uint16_t syn:1;
    uint16_t rst:1;
    uint16_t psh:1;
    uint16_t ack:1;
    uint16_t urg:1;
    uint16_t res2:2;
# elif __BYTE_ORDER == __BIG_ENDIAN
    uint16_t doff:4;
    uint16_t res1:4;
    uint16_t res2:2;
    uint16_t urg:1;
    uint16_t ack:1;
    uint16_t psh:1;
    uint16_t rst:1;
    uint16_t syn:1;
    uint16_t fin:1;
# else
#  error "Adjust your <bits/endian.h> defines"
# endif
    uint16_t window;
    uint16_t check;
    uint16_t urg_ptr;
      };
    };
};
```

[image]

Comment: `int i=iph->ihl*4;` <<-- looks wrong. ( ... `ip->ihl         = 5; ip->version     = 4;` <<-- unless you have the fields defined as bitfields, which you shouldn't, IMHO )

Comment: @wildplasser `int i=iph->ihl*4; <<-- ... wrong. ( ... ip->ihl =5;ip->version= 4; <<-- unless you have the fields defined as bitfields,)` U mean my ip header length(which is ip->ihl*4) is  wrong because this is NOT exactly reflect the sizeof my ip header length?

Comment: @wildplasser U further said what u do mean `unless you have the fields defined as bitfields` actually they are `unsigned int ihl:4` for `iphdr->ihl` and `uint8_t protocol` why do u think there is something wrong about my these fields: 1) Is it because my ihl does not reflect the sizeof ip header?2)what `unless you have the fields defined as bitfields` means they are `unsigned int ihl:4` `uint8_t`

Comment: its same as `struct iphdr` on Ubuntu 21 and kernel `5.13`

Comment: So it **are** bitfields. Without the headers, your question is incomplete, and we can only guess.

Comment: @wildplasser Please see the how  `struct iphdr` and `struct tcphdr` looks like on my system with Ubuntu 21. implementation probably part of glibc in netinet/tcp.h and netinet/ip.h. Can u please look at the updated structs in my question that just added

Comment: also can any one please tell me on this `tcp->ack_seq=htons(ntohs(tcph->seq)+1);` is it correct this way I am assigning value to ack_seq (acknowledgement number) number to send tcp header field `ack_seq` in response of sequence number of received packet and tcph in this line is received TCP packet so I believe that acknowledgement number is acknowledges the the reception of last sequence number added one. Or please tell me correct way of generating ack_seq number for reponse of received tcp packet including SYN received packets plus what would be acknowlegment number for received ACK packet

Comment: to be focused on wireshark in flags it says instead of showing flags message `TCP SYN-ACK accepting TFO data` why wireshark not showing res urgent flag psh flag why its not showing instead its giving me message in flags that  `TCP SYN-ACK acceping TFP data` what this mean?

Comment: @wildplasser ip header length is not the issue, the packet starts with 0x45 which is correct, also wireshark has parsed it as ip header, this means that version is correct

Comment: @user786 can you post wireshark screenshot for the received SYN packet? I have a feeling that it has options in it, which you ignore. Ignoring options is ok. But then you copy doff from the original packet and it does not match.

Comment: @Effie why wireshark is not showing my TCP flags. Its just saying `TCP SYN-ACK accepting TFO data` its not showing `urgent pointer flag URG, or SYN flag or ACK flag, or RES1 flag or RES2 flag or PSH flag`  separately. WHAT TFO EVEN MEANS?

Comment: @user786 also, out of curiosity, what is the goal of your project. Assuming you get the handshake, implementing segmentation/reassembly and flow control is quite nontrivial task.

Comment: @Effie `also out of curiosity` I may learn TCP plus this way and only this way to be focused since I love this type of coding

Comment: your wireshark screenshot only shows fields up to the field with flags. Can you make a screenshot that shows full packet

Comment: @Effie `your wireshark screenshot only shows fields up to the field with flags. Can you make a screenshot that shows full packet ` I have attached the Screenshot of no TCP flags showing by my wireshark just saying `Accepting TFO data` I think this is the very reason my TCP packet sending from my code is labeled by wireshark as malformed and wire shark message showing  `Does not contain  a full TCP header` message in Wireshark

Comment: no, it is labeled mailformed because tcp data offset (aka the length of tcp header) is 40, but the packet is only 40 bytes long, 20 of which is IP header.

Comment: @Effie my this code is executing and it shows I am setting flags the wireshark isnt displaying my flags `if(tcph->syn==1)
    {
           printf("WHAT THE HELL THEN WHY\n"); 
 
         populate_tcp_some(tcph,tcp);
         tcp->seq=htons(1);
         tcp->ack_seq=1;
         tcp->syn=1;
         tcp->ack=1;
         tcp->res1=0;
         tcp->res1=0;
         tcp->urg=0;
         tcp->psh=0;
         tcp->fin=0;
         tcp->doff=tcph->doff; 
         tcp->source=htons(80);
         tcp->ack_seq=htons(ntohs(tcph->seq)+1);
 
  }`

Comment: `tcp->doff=tcph->doff;` this line is a problem. I think it should be `tcp->doff = 5`

Comment: @Effie `no, it is labeled mailformed because tcp data offset (aka the length of tcp header) is 40, but the packet is only 40 bytes long, 20 of which is IP heade` yes this is the point 20 bytes of TCP header and 20 bytes of IP header plus 0 byte of payload, when do TCP handshake packet started carrying more than 40 byte total. Am I wrong do I need to send  some test data with TCP handshake packets?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240533/discussion-between-effie-and-user786).

Comment: @Effie I tried like `tcp->doff=5` still same message TCP- ACCEPTING TSO data `Short segment. Segment/fragment does not contain a full TCP header (might be NMAP or someone else deliberately sending unusual packets)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have an answer to the question.

OP is trying to create a SYNACK packet to answer incomming SYN packet. TCP SYN packet is generated from an OS stack, and uses Options.

Wireshark complains that header is too short. It can be seen, that header length in the tcp header is set to 40 bytes, while the actual header present is only 20 bytes (the whole packet is 40 bytes: 20 bytes IP header and 20 bytes tcp header).

The issue is that the field `tcp->doff`, which is tcp header, length is copied from the incomming SYN packet. Although not shown, incomming SYN packet presumably has TCP options in it, and thus its header is 40 bytes, not 20 bytes. Thus copying `tcp->doff` leads to the error message in quesition.

For the reference, tcp header length field is tcp header length in multiples of 32 bits, or 4 bytes. Minimal tcp header is 20 bytes or 5 tcp header units. Alternatively `tcp->doff = sizeof(struct tcphdr)/4` should work too.